# Error in path updating android sdk components

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

A few days ago I decided to change the Windows 10 username, unfortunately I discovered after that that there was a bug that left the user without access on some computers. After I managed to access the computer I created a new user (in addition to the adm). However, Android Studio is downloading to an old user folder (pictured: Ronaldo, which no longer exists). In Android Studio the configuration of the SDK folder is right, it even shows all the previous packages installed, but to update it always tries in the old folder. I have already deleted all known folders (in appdata/local/roaming and others), looked at the windows registry, reinstalled Android Studio and nothing. Always the same problem.

All possible solutions I found were in the sense of access permissions, setting the location of the sdk directory, but nothing like that.

Thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lmf9x.png)

Answer (score 0):

Start Regedit.exe, go to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Android Studio` and make sure that the `SdkPath` and `UserSettingsPath` values are pointing to the new user profile, and not `C:\Users\Ronaldo` (`SdkPath` can be empty)

Also worth looking in the file(s) in `%userprofile%\.android\studio\installer`

Comment: They are all correct, I had already looked through the entire registry looking for some unknown entry. When I reinstalled Android I searched and deleted all known folders to make sure there was no xml (or similar) file with configuration data. Strange thing is that when it goes to update it displays the folder where the sdk is, but when I click finish and starts installing the component it shows the error with the wrong folder.

Comment: The reference to that old path can only be in the registry or in a file in`%userprofile%\.android` or in one of the `.xml` config files in `%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio2020.3`, or `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2020.3` (if you're using the latest AS stable version). Look in `%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio2020.3\options\updates.xml`. I would say if you really deleted all those folders before re-installing, the reference to the old path should have gone, too. Maybe you re-installed without deleting the old config completely?

Comment: I had already deleted it. When I did the reinstallation I also deleted all these folders again, looked for all the Android references (besides the ones I already knew) and did the deletion before installing again. I searched the registry for the wrong username and Android to delete, revised the environment variables. I've been in this battle for a few days, and there must be some other place where it was stored that I don't know about. What I've been doing is downloading the packages/components I need, and then playing in the sdk folder (which it normally recognizes).

Comment: Obs.: Some it updates right in the sdk manager (those that I mark for download), only the ones it asks for update that this happens.